# How can I decrement file names in python?

Tags: python, windows, image

I have a directory with web camera images that are constantly incrementing. I would like to use a python script to get the most recent 10 images. Currently I have the following code for getting the most recent image. I would like to decrement the file name and get the most recent 10 images and name them image_current1.jpg to image_current10.jpg.

```
import os
import glob

from PIL import Image
from shutil import copyfile

# variables 
rawFileDir = 'C:\pictures\image00*.jpg'
mriFileName = 'C:\pictures\image_current1.jpg'

# obtain and copy most recent image
mostRecentImage = max(glob.iglob(rawFileDir), key=os.path.getctime)
copyfile(mostRecentImage,mriFileName)
```

Comment: `imgs = glob.glob('C:\pictures\image*.jpg')` will create a list of all your images. You can then access last 10 elements like this `imgs[-10:]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use sorted list from `glob.iglob(rawFileDir)`:

```
import os
import glob

from PIL import Image
from shutil import copyfile

# variables 
rawFileDir = 'E:\Test\image00*.jpg'
mriFileName = 'E:\Test\image_current'

# obtain and copy most recent image
mostRecentImage = sorted(glob.iglob(rawFileDir), key=os.path.getctime)
for num, i in enumerate(mostRecentImage[:~10:-1]):
    exec('copyfile(i, mriFileName + str({}) + ".jpg")'.format(num + 1))
```

`image_current1.jpg` will be the most recent file.

Answer (score 0):

This will provide a dictionary of the desired filenames (e.g. image_current01.jpg) and the target file.

```
{'image_current' + str(n).zfill(1): filename 
 for n, filename in enumerate(sorted((os.path.getctime(f), f) 
 for f in glob.glob('*.jpg'))[-10::][::-1])}
```